# Como atribuir nova categoria no magento?

Tags: magento

Estou tentando adicionar uma nova categoria e atribui-la a um produto, porém o produto não é exibido na pagina principal.

```
Root Catalog (categoria principal)
 |--Joias (categoria joias)
     |-- ouro
     |-- prata
     |-- pingente
 |--Alianças (categoria alianças)
```

Quando instalei o tema que comprei ele já veio com algumas categorias criadas então eu reaproveitei e apenas renomeei, até ai tudo bem, o produto aparece normal, mas caso eu selecione o produto da nova categoria que criei ele não aparece.